# Evaluate $\int {\frac{{x + 1}}{{x{{\left( {1 + x{e^x}} \right)}^2}}}dx} $

Tags: integration

Evaluate $\int {\frac{{x + 1}}{{x{{\left( {1 + x{e^x}} \right)}^2}}}dx} $

My approach is as follow

$\int {\frac{{x + 1}}{{x{{\left( {1 + x{e^x}} \right)}^2}}}dx}  \Rightarrow \int {\frac{{x + 1}}{{x\left( {{e^{2x}}} \right){{\left( {{e^{ - x}} + x} \right)}^2}}}dx}  \Rightarrow \int {\frac{{\left( {{e^{ - 2x}}} \right)\left( {1 + \frac{1}{x}} \right)}}{{{{\left( {{e^{ - x}} + x} \right)}^2}}}dx}  \Rightarrow \int {\frac{{\left( {{e^{ - 2x}}} \right)\left( {1 + \frac{1}{x}} \right)}}{{{x^2}{{\left( {\frac{{{e^{ - x}}}}{x} + 1} \right)}^2}}}dx} $

$ \Rightarrow \int {\frac{{\left( {{e^{ - 2x}}} \right)\left( {\frac{1}{{{x^2}}} + \frac{1}{{{x^3}}}} \right)}}{{\left( {\frac{{{e^{ - 2x}}}}{{{x^2}}} + \frac{{2{e^{ - x}}}}{x} + 1} \right)}}dx} $

How do I approach from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $$u = 1 + x e^x, \quad du = (x e^x + x) \, dx = (1 + x) e^x \, dx,$$ we have $$\int \frac{1+x}{x(1+xe^x)^2} \, dx = \int \frac{(1+x)e^x}{x e^x (1 + xe^x)^2} \, dx = \int \frac{du}{(u-1) u^2}.$$  Then partial fraction decomposition yields
$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{du}{(u-1) u^2} &= \int \frac{1}{u-1}  - \frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{u^2} \, du \\
&= \log|u-1| - \log |u| + u^{-1} + C \\
&= \log|x| + x - \log|1 + xe^x| + \frac{1}{1 + xe^x} + C.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Set $1+xe^x=y$

Multiply numerator and denominator by $e^x$

Now $$\dfrac1{y(y-1)}=\dfrac{y-(y-1)}{y(y-1)}=?$$